# UITableViewCell with UILabel content changing on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please check below code and image for understanding ,

I used `UITableView` for profile edit and each cell contain `UILabel` with old data. After entering new details and scroll it automatically values are changes to old data.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return identifiersAry.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EditProfileTableViewCell *cell = (EditProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[identifiersAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case NAME_CELL:
            nameTxtFld = cell.firstNameTxtLbl;
            name = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            cell.firstNameTxtLbl.text = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            break;

        case UserName_Cell:
            userNameTxtFld = cell.userNameTxtFld;
            cell.userNameTxtFld.text = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"userName"];            
            break;

        default:
            break;
   }

   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

   return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Its because you're using values from NSUserDefaults, not from your instance variables. You need to store current values of each textfields and need to display it and use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Why dont you use static tableviewcontroller? With that you will able to outlet different variable for textfield of different cell.

Comment: Do you save data when user enters it? If not it will read from `NSUserDefaults` which will still hold old data...

Comment: I given answer for my question check it once and its working for me if any modifications please share @Ladislav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Solved, I just take initial bool values with 'YES' , when it loaded at first time all data stored from NSUserDefaults, when Last cell is loaded then I just change 'NO' values then its working for me Thank you.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return identifiersAry.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EditProfileTableViewCell *cell = (EditProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[identifiersAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case NAME_CELL:
            nameTxtFld = cell.firstNameTxtLbl;
            name = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            if (isEnteringFirstTime)
            cell.firstNameTxtLbl.text = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            break;

        case UserName_Cell:
            userNameTxtFld = cell.userNameTxtFld;
            if (isEnteringFirstTime)
            cell.userNameTxtFld.text = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"userName"];  
           isEnteringFirstTime = NO;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```